# Nodejs pass formdata foreward

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data

Front end => Middel service => End service

My front end sends a file to my nodejs service by doing this:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        resolve(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
}

var data = new FormData();
data.append('file', event.target.files[0]);

xmlHttp.open('POST', '.../utUploadFile');
xmlHttp.send(data);
```

My End service then catches this and saves the file:

```
app.post('/utUploadFile', async (request, response, next) => {
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(request, async function (err, fields, files) {
        ...save the 'files'
    });
});
```

My question is, how do I add a middle layer to this, how to I just take the front end request, and pass the same thing on to the End service to do its work:

```
const http = require('request');
...
app.post(`/utUploadFile`, (request, response, next) => {
    http.post({
        headers: {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'},
        url: `.../utUploadFile`,
        body: JSON.stringify(request.body)
    }, (err, res, body) => {

    });
});
```

Comment: You could do that or use [express-http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy)

Comment: AWESOME suggestion, thank you! But I am now getting an error `Error: MultipartParser.end(): stream ended unexpectedly: state = START_BOUNDARY` at `form.parse(request, async function (err, fields, files) {// this err});`